# Compare Neighbors in Reversed Deque

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, collections, deque

I have the following Python3 MWE:

```
import collections

N = 5
d = collections.deque(maxlen=N)
d.append(1)
d.append(2)
d.append(3)

for x,y in zip(list(d)[::-1], list(d)[::-1][1:]):
  print(x-y)
```

The deque is reversed, and most recently added items are compared with their neighbors, until all neighbors are compared (max number of comparisons is N-1).

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I think my solution is pretty Pythonic, but I cannot judge the efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

do you need the deque for your program?
i would go with the numpy approach , which is much faster
( in higher number its very significate)

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3,5,8,13,21])
print(arr[1:] - arr[0:-1])
```

my code took 220 ns 
you method took 812 ns
and the difference will grow with the amount of data

i would note that appending into a numpy array isnt efficient , you would want
to append into a list (which is O(1)) and convert it into a np array
np array append is O(N)

Comment: Interesting solution. However, the datastructure should work like a ringbuffer. And the deque is the closest thing in Python (or is it?)

Comment: @JJAbrams I don’t see enough similarities between a ring buffer and a deque, creating a class ring is needed in python since there is no overwriting in deque, it’s just a 2 sided list, besides , for efficient , creating a ring data type with operation based on numpy will improve runtime significantly

Comment: I am stupid. I meant a FIFO, not a ringbuffer :(
Please excuse me.

Comment: @JJAbrams actually a deque is FIFO and LIFO depends how you use it , in python standard library there is also a Queue, which is a pure FIFO

Comment: @masana Ah, interesting, there is a Python buildin FIFO? But judging the collections site (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html), they are "High-performance container datatypes" (higher performance, than the Python buildin ones?). If I need a FIFO, would you say, that my approach is the "best"?

Comment: @JJAbrams i think Queue and deque has the same Big-O Notation , but https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html can be only FIFO, i think it is preferred that if you want only FIFO, dont use a datatype that support appending and popping from both sides, more even if you program with more people who might have a bad use with your datatype

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding the creation of lists when processing deque objects would be more efficient (1.3 times faster):

```
prevd = iter(reversed(d))
next(prevd)
for value,previous in zip(reversed(d), prevd):
    print(value-previous)
```

*If you are starting from data in a deque and producing a list of differences, this will be faster than using numpy (because of the overhead of creating the numpy array and turning the result back into a list at the end).  You would have to commit to numpy all the way to get its full benefits but then you may end up paying a higher price on other operations such as appending to the array*

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a more performance version! But should that example, you posted, work?

Comment: I tested it.  That's how I was able to measure the performance differences.